# valet in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laravel-valet, valet

Today I decided to install Valet on Windows 10. But I got this error:

```
Could not start the phpfpmservice service. Check ~/.valet/Log for errors.
~/.valet/Log has file nginx-error which is empty.
```

I tried to run valet start with admin privilages but I get the same error

Answer (score 4):

Open the terminal in **Administrator Mode** then run

```
valet stop
valet uninstall
valet install
```

That will do.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by doing those steps.

and this problem arrived after updating the windows machine.

Ensure that the terminal is in Administrator Mode before running.

First, we need to stop valet and uninstall valet from the system.

```
valet stop
valet uninstall
```

after uninstall now install valet on your system by running this command

```
valet install
```

This will work